# Weird error while parsing JSON in Apache Spark

Tags: java, json, apache-spark

Trying to parse a JSON document and Spark gives me an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Since Spark 2.3, the queries from raw JSON/CSV files are disallowed when the
referenced columns only include the internal corrupt record column
   (named _corrupt_record by default). For example:
spark.read.schema(schema).json(file).filter($"_corrupt_record".isNotNull).count()
and spark.read.schema(schema).json(file).select("_corrupt_record").show().
Instead, you can cache or save the parsed results and then send the same query.
For example, val df = spark.read.schema(schema).json(file).cache() and then
df.filter($"_corrupt_record".isNotNull).count().;
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JsonFileFormat.buildReader(JsonFileFormat.scala:120)
...
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3364)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2545)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2759)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:255)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:292)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:746)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:705)
at xxx.MyClass.xxx(MyClass.java:25)
```

I already tried to open the JSON doc in several online editors and it's valid.

This is my code:

```
Dataset<Row> df = spark.read()
    .format("json")
    .load("file.json");

df.show(3); // this is line 25
```

I am using Java 8 and Spark 2.4.

Answer (score 3):

The `_corrupt_record` column is where Spark stores malformed records when it tries to ingest them. That could be a hint.

Spark also process two types of JSON documents, JSON Lines and normal JSON (in the earlier versions Spark could only do JSON Lines). You can find more in this [Manning article](https://freecontent.manning.com/ingesting-data-from-files-with-spark-part-2/).

You can try the `multiline` option, as in:

```
Dataset<Row> df = spark.read()
    .format("json")
    .option("multiline", true)
    .load("file.json");
```

to see if it helps. If not, share your JSON doc (if you can).

Answer (score -1):

set the multiline option to true. If it does not work share your json

Comment: Please explain how this answers the question. This should be a comment.

Comment: had the same error trace. I set the multiline to true and then it worked. look at this link https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18352 and note that if there is a json parse exception we get this error